# Error using functions inside of a class. I can't assign a function to a new class method

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a new method for my class 'Cloth', the method is called 'max_temp' and, to ease the task, i created the following function (max_temperature) to keep a cleaner code in the **init** part.
I can't understand why it doesn't calculate the 'max_temp' method tho

```
class cloth():
    def __init__(self, category, name):
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.max_temp = max_temperature(category)

    def max_temperature(category):
        temps = {
            'sweater' : 24,
            'shirt' : 45}
        return temps[category]

x = cloth('sweater', 'cam_eco')

print(x.max_temp)
```

```
>>> print(x.max_temp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: `self.max_temp = self.max_temperature(category)` and add `self` argument to `max_temperature`.

Comment: Or don't add `self` to the parameters and make your method a `@staticmethod`, as it doesn't make use of any attribute of the instance or the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a method inside a class then it needs to be either passed `self` as the first argument, or define it as a `staticmethod` or `classmethod`. Otherwise you need to define it outside the class.

So `max_temperature` needs to declared as one of:

```
@staticmethod # or @classmethod (Ill leave looking up the difference to you)
def max_temperature(category):
    ....
```

or

```
def max_temperature(self, category):
    ....
```

or define it outside the class.

If you define it inside the class then you should call it via `self` (or the class name if its a classmethod):

```
class cloth: # Note I removed the () from the class
    def __init__(self, category, name):
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.max_temp = self.max_temperature(category)
...
```

So overall:

```
class cloth:
    def __init__(self, category, name):
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.max_temp = self.max_temperature(category)

    @staticmethod
    def max_temperature(category): # TODO you should add error handling to this method
        temps = {
            'sweater' : 24,
            'shirt' : 45
        }
        return temps[category]

x = cloth('sweater', 'cam_eco')
print(x.max_temp) # 24
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been already answered by Austin, but If you are not ok with static concept yet, then your code will look like

```
    class cloth():
        def __init__(self, category, name):
            self.category = category
            self.name = name
            self.max_temp = self.max_temperature(category)

        def max_temperature(self,category):
            temps = {'sweater' : 24,'shirt' : 45}

            return temps[category]

    x = cloth('sweater', 'cam_eco')

    print(x.max_temp)
```

Comment: This is exactly the second version given in the previous, upvoted answer by  @Error - Syntactical Remorse.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using self.category as the argument in the max_temperature function?

```
class cloth():
    def __init__(self, category, name):
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.max_temp = max_temperature(category)

    def max_temperature(self, self.category):
        temps = {
            'sweater' : 24,
            'shirt' : 45}
        return temps[category]

x = cloth('sweater', 'cam_eco')

print(x.max_temp)
```

Comment: Is that even legal? And why would you do that?

Comment: Python's answer: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`... Please don't post code that doesn't even work.